# Partition of Array by Element given X

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, compiler-errors, partition

> I Am Trying To Find **Partition Of Array** ,On Condition By Checking Variable x ,**when less then x they will be on one side or else on another.** but my code need some correction.
> HERE am not able to find the error , i  will be thankful to you if you help me.
> Code is:-

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int partition(int arr[],int n,int x){
    for(int i=0;i<n;){
        if(arr[i]<x){
            i++;
        }
        else if(arr[i]==x){   
            int temp=arr[i];
            arr[i]=arr[n];
            arr[n]=temp;
            i--;
        }
        else if(arr[i]>x){
            int temp=arr[i];
            for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
                arr[j]=arr[j+1];   
            }
            arr[n]=temp;
           i--;
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    int arr[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>arr[i];    
    }
    int x;
    cin>>x;
    
    partition(arr,n,x);
    
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
     }
    return 0;
}
```

> `Input >> array={2,10,15,1,3,15} ,x=10`

> `Expected << {2,1,3,10,15,15}`

> `Output I get << nothing .`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This code does not compile; please post the code you're actually using. Also, the best thing to do in this case is *debug the program.* This is a basic skill which every programmer must learn.

Comment: ...And at first glance, your function reads past the end of the array, which causes *undefined behavior.* (If you don't know what that is, look it up.)

Comment: Can you please kindly inform, if you are lookong for a stable partition or a normal unstable partition. Your expected output looks like a stable partitition, but in the question, you just say "partition" Also your solution looks more like "unstable" partition. This information is very important. I assume you mean "unstable" . . .

Answer (score 1):

The code isn't giving any output because, first, the "cin" and "cout" are in upper case which is syntactically incorrect, secondly, the variable j is in different case in loop statement and body inside the second else-if clause in the partition function, same goes for the "I" in the first for loop in the main() function. Sort this out and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

**First** in C++ the size of an array must be a **compile-time constant**. So for example, consider the following examples:

```
int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT
```

The correct way to write the above would be:

```
const int n = 10;
int arr[n]; //CORRECT
```

Similarly, in your code,

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int arr[n]; //INCORRECT because n is not a constant expression
```

**Second**, in your code, when you wrote:

```
arr[n] = temp; Undefined behavior
```

you're going **out of bounds** and so you have **undefined behavior**.

##### Solution

You can use [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) and `std::vector` to solve your problem as shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout <<"Enter n:"<<std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    
    std::vector<int> arr(n); //create a vector of size n instead of an array 
    
    std::cout<<"Enter elements: "<<std::endl;
    //iterate and take input from user
    for(int &elem: arr){
        std::cin >> elem ;     
    }
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter x: "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>x;
    
    //use std::partition
    std::stable_partition(arr.begin(), arr.end(), [x](int i){return (i < x);});
    
    std::cout<<"This is the partitioned vector: "<<std::endl;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        std::cout<<arr[i]<<"\t";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

##### Output

The output of the above program is as follows:

```
Enter n:
6
Enter elements: 
2
10
15
1
3
15
Enter x: 
10
This is the partitioned vector: 
2       1       3       10      15      15
```

which can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/zU-A7FsPN).

Comment: One very kind recommendation after reading you profile. Stop using `std::endl` for `std::cout`. 2nd recommendation. Try to adapt to the question and the programming style of the OP.  You use `std::stable_partition` but the OP want to do this manually. So, your good answer with you explanations, that I really like, goes somehow in the wrong direction. Do not misunderstand me. You answer is good.

Comment: @ArminMontigny Thanks for your recommendations.For your 2nd recommendation,i was thinking of writing(adding it in my answer) a manual way of partitioning for the OP but didn't get enough time to work on it.So i thought its better to point out the mistake in the current program and at least let OP know(if he/she doesn't already know) that there is a built in way of doing this.It may happen that the OP was unaware of `std::stable_partition` so for that case this answer might be helpful. Maybe i will add manual way of partitioning if i get the time.For now *i did as much as i could*.Thanks again.